# Click on markers en go to different activities

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps-markers

For my project in school I have to make an app that tours you through the school. Now I want to make the markers on my map clickable and make the them go to different activities with info of the POI's. I know about the onMarkerListeners and intents, but I don't know how to implement this.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    int height = 100;
    int width = 100;
    BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
    Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    LatLng HalA = new LatLng(50.8062795, 3.2922986);
    LatLng stuvo = new LatLng(50.8061347, 3.2920485);
    LatLng bib = new LatLng(50.8062763,3.2919120);
    LatLng acco = new LatLng(50.8063492,3.2925983);
```

There are more POI's, but this is irrelevant. The following code is how i put my markers on the map.

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HalA)
            .title("Hal A")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(stuvo)
            .title("Stuvo")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
```

and so on. Where do I have to place my onMarkerListener? Do I have to put everything in the onCreate? What do I have to change?